How do I utilize the data aggregator integrations?
I've read through so many pages of the developer documentation, but I can't find any mention of how to connect with the integrations that are offered, such as the data aggregators listed on this page [1]. Could someone please help me understand how this relates to the consumer API, and how I could begin using this to build a personal finance management app?
[1] https://banno.com/data-aggregators/

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The short answer
The short answer is that the Banno Digital Toolkit doesn't offer access to the Data Aggregators.
There are other solutions out in the industry that aggregate-the-aggregators, but the Banno Digital Toolkit is not one of them.
The long answer
The Data Aggregators use the Consumer API and the Authentication Framework from the Banno Digital Toolkit to make accounts, balances, transactions, and user identity info from Banno-powered financial institutions available outside of Banno i.e. so account holders at those institutions can connect their accounts to their favorite fintech apps.
Some confusion might arise since Finicity is on the list of Data Aggregators that make Banno data available outside of Banno to fintech apps, and it also has a special relationship with Jack Henry to pull data into Banno from outside sources e.g. other financial institutions, via the Connected Accounts feature.
